# HERE tour planning api problem with multiple delivery in single job

Tags: here-api, here-tourplanning

We are implementing route optimization for a fleet management system, there we have a case like that in a single Job we have 1 pickup and 10 delivery point. so for this solution we are using VRP Multi-jobs.

It's working fine until 3 delivery points but when delivery point is more then 3 then is showing some errors

```
{
   "title": "OpenApi validation error",
   "status": 400,
   "code": "E613000",
   "cause": "[Path '\/plan\/jobs\/1\/tasks\/deliveries'] Array is too long: must have 
    at most 3 elements but instance has 4 elements",
   "action": "Problem definition is not consistent with the specification. Please 
    correct problem and send it again.",
   "correlationId": "15fd607c-b53c-42fa-8317-ef60fcc4bedd"
}
```

How can we solve this things?

Answer (score 0):

The error description has the solution for the issue faced: max of the delivery/pickups Is 3 per job. It’s limitation of the current implementation that is mentioned in the API spec:
[image]
The option to solve the issue is to split tasks to separate jobs. In case of using 1 vehicle pickup job could have earlier time window than delivery jobs.
KS

Comment: In case the problem is more complicated more details are required. For example, why pickup point can’t be set as the depot point?